# SCO box not turning on: how to diagnose issue?

Tags: motherboard, power-supply

Today my old sco box stopped working, I have tested the psu (a Macron MPT-301), and it is working. The MBO is the Intel G7ESZ Server Board, and I believe it could be that.

Would anyone have any possible tests I could run on this motherboard to confirm it is that, which is fried?

Comment: Is this just a PC?  Does it post?

Comment: Yeah it's a PC, not sure. How can I confirm that ?

Comment: The pc doesn't power on at all. No beep either, so I believe it wont be posting.

Comment: The system is running on the SCO Openserver 5. Can I not just remove the hard-drive and place it into another pc ? Or am I being stupid ?

Comment: i havent even seen SCO used in 20+ years.  You can try, it might not work or detect hardware if the new machine is vastly different from the original

Comment: Yeah it's very old. I need to make sure the data is kept too. It is vital!

Comment: Took it to a specialist who said it is beyond repair, no lights on mobo. :(